# How can I know when a memory request is forwarded to another numa node, which node is it?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, performancecounter, numa

When a memory access happens in node A, but it is a remote access, which is forwarded to node B, through QuickPath Interconnect controller.

Different node has different range of memory address, so of course I can use the memory address to identify this.

If I don't know the memory address, can I use some hardware register or performance counter to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't have address**, use [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) framework to collect overall statistics (events you seek to are called node-*). Tool will show number of misses/overall events for loads, stores and prefetches.

perf may be called from userspace, in per-thread collection mode, thus you may use `rdpmc` assembly instruction and read individual performance counter. I.e. read counter before and after memory access and calculate difference.

I created a small sample using my old code, but I can't test it right now :(
Here it is: https://gist.github.com/myaut/cd67ea5143615264b2e6

**If you have address**, you may use `page_zone()` and `virt_to_page()` kernel functions to get nodeid for address (where `ptr` is virtual address):

```
struct zone* z = page_zone(virt_to_page((void*) ptr));
return z->node;
```

I used this to track memory accesses in kernel using [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Sure I can use perf to collect overall memory misses or loads. But how can I identify them: If they are remote memory access, which nodes they are to? Is perf provide such different counter ?

Comment: @procr, you may try to seek some hardware QPI counters. I'm not sure they exists or representative. Intel PMUs are described in http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html Vol. 3B, Chapter 19. Or you need address.